# The loading screen for my website isn't disappearing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-animations

I am loading a large image for the background of my website, so instead of having it messy I decided to add a nice little preloader with CSS and Jquery.

Right inside the `<body>` tag I have:

```
<!-- CSS Spinner -->
<div class="spinner-wrapper">
    <div class="spinner">
        <div class="rect1"></div>
        <div class="rect2"></div>
        <div class="rect3"></div>
        <div class="rect4"></div>
        <div class="rect5"></div>
        <em class="spinner-text">One moment</em>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then, before the closing `</body>` tag I have this script:

```
<!-- Spinner -->
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(window).load(function() {
            preloaderFadeOutTime = 500;

            function hidePreloader() {
                var preloader = $('.spinner-wrapper');
                preloader.fadeOut(preloaderFadeOutTime);
            }
            hidePreloader();
        });
    });
</script>
```

When I open the index.html file directly, it works perfectly, but when I was trying to load it on my website ([link](http://iampjt.com/ElonCR)) it just shows the preloader forever.

Interestingly, I've found that if I open the network panel in the developer console, most of the time the preloader works as it is supposed to.

Does anyone know what the heck is going on here?

Comment: Did you add `jQuery` on your website? :)

Comment: @Kinduser yes! It's down towards the end of the file but still before the script I am using. Should I move it to the <head>?

Comment: I'm not sure but won't harm if you try :)

Comment: Really strange...I moved JQuery into the <head> and then turned off the Cloudflare "RocketLoader" thing and it's working now. If you want to write that into an answer, I can mark it as correct.

Comment: Done. I'm glad that I could help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to import your `jQuery` inside the `head` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this attribute (data-cfasync="false") within JS will not work to exclude the script from Rocket Loader. Rocket Loader ignore individual scripts by adding the data-cfasync="false" attribute to the relevant script tag, for example:

```
<script data-cfasync="false" src="/javascript.js"></script>
```